# Can't rename world after adding "color"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I decided to rename my world in color but then I accidentally pressed backspace so I went to type it in again and it won't let me. I have no idea what to do and it was my favorite world. I DONT WANT TO LEAVE IT NAME LESS. Any suggestions? I also don't want to delete that world or delete minecraft because I have spent so much time on it. Thanks

Comment: Renaming the folder would give you that small name under your bigger name. You can also duplicate and rename your world. I am also trying to experiment with the `level.dat` file that every world has. Will come back with results

Comment: I saw your answer post. Please avoid posting non-answer content as it is intended for answers only. Instead, comment. You need 50 rep for other posts, but you can comment on yours and I think my answer too. Anyway, If you have access to the game's saves, you can

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the name of your world after applied changes with an NBT editor like NBTEdit or NBTExplorer.

This is how you would do it for NBT explorer:

Open up your NBT Explorer and navigate to the `level.dat` file in your save folder.

[image]

You will see many options for your world. Here, you scroll down to the Level Name tag, and edit it with the **EDIT** option on the top.

[image]

Then you can save, and also rename your world folder (the one inside saves) so you have the gray name on the bottom also. I did not test this, but I think you can use color codes in here too.

```
\00002A\This is Blue
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this glitch is on mine raft PE. Would your solution still work?

Comment: It should, as long as you have access to some sort of level.dat on minecraft PE. Perhaps make a backup and download it to your PC